# Skype on 11.10 x64

Tags: 11.10, fonts, skype

Why Skype crashes on 11.10 x64 architecture? And why the weird font ? Why its not using the system font, like it's set in Options ? The same problem is in 12.04, but that's forgivable for pre-realese verson...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the steps described here? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SkypeTroubleshooting#Display_configuration

At one point I couldn't even read the fonts on the menu's, and following this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Skype is still in Beta 2, so technically this application is also in pre-release. Unfortunately it's been in that state for quite some time, however I've been using it for months and rarely have a problem with it.

> skype-ubuntu_2.2.0.35-1_amd64.deb

http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/

Can you be a little more specific and elaborate a bit on the crashes?   Do you see any messages of value in **/var/log/syslog** when the crashes occur?

Comment: Just to add, after Microsoft bought Skype I have even less faith that it will ever come out of Beta.